Neukirch A.N.T Proposition 4.5 doubt
Neukirch A.N.T Proposition 4.5
Proposition
The canonical mapping
$$
O \longmapsto \lim_{{n\leftarrow}} O/p^n
$$
is an isomorphism and a homeomorphism. The same is true for the mapping
$$
O^* \longmapsto \lim_{{n\leftarrow}} O^*/U(n).
$$
$\textbf{Proof:}$ The map is injective since its kernel is
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} p^n = (0).
$$
To prove surjectivity, let $p = \pi O$ and let $R \subset O, R \neq 0$, be a system of representatives of $O/p$. We saw in the proof of (4.4) (and in fact already in (1.2)) that the elements $a \mod p^n \in O/p^n$ can be given uniquely in the form
$$
a \equiv a_0 + a_1 \pi + \cdots + a_{n-1} \pi^{n-1} \mod p^n,
$$
where $a_i \in R$. Each element $s \in \lim_{n \to \infty} O/p^n$ is therefore given by a sequence of sums
$$
s_n = a_0 + a_1 \pi + \cdots + a_{n-1} \pi^{n-1}, \quad n = 1, 2, \ldots,
$$
with fixed coefficients $a_i \in R$, and it is thus the image of the element
$$
x = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = \sum_{v=0}^{\infty} a_v \pi^v \in O.
$$
The sets $P_n = \prod_{v > n} {O/p^v }$ form a basis of neighbourhoods of the zero element of $\lim_{v \to \infty} O/p^v$. Under the bijection
$$
O \longrightarrow \lim_{{v\leftarrow}} O/p^v.
$$
the basis of neighbourhoods $p^n$ of zero in $O$ is mapped onto the basis of
neighbourhoods $P_n \cap \lim_{{\nu\leftarrow}} O/p^{\nu}$ of zero in $\lim_{\nu\leftarrow} O/p^{\nu}$. Thus the bijection is
a homeomorphism. It induces an isomorphism and homeomorphism on the group of units
$$
O^* \cong \left( \lim_{n\leftarrow} O/p^n \right)^* \cong \lim_{n\leftarrow} \left( O/p^n \right)^* \cong \lim_{n\leftarrow} O^*/U(n).
$$
My question
(1) Is there quotient topology on $O/p^n$  ? if not then what are the opens sets ?
(2) How basis are mapped onto basis ?
(3) Why $\left( \lim_{n\leftarrow} O/p^n \right)^* \cong \lim_{n\leftarrow} \left( O/p^n \right)^*$ ?

(1) Taken individually, the quotients $O/pO$ have the discrete topology.
(2) The proof you've copied in your question above already answers this question. The relevant topology on $O$ is the metric topology induced by the given $p$-adic valuation. If you're familiar with how non-archimedean valuations determine absolute values (which in turn determine metrics, hence a topology), then it should be clear that the sets $p^n$ form a basis of neighborhoods of $0$ in $O$ (if you're not, you should go back and spend some more time with the initial sections of chapter 2 of Neukirch). It suffices to consider only these open sets and to show that they map to a neighborhood basis of $O$ in $\underset{n}{\underset{ \leftarrow}{\lim}} O/p^nO$, since both this inverse limit and $O$ are topological groups. The fact that the canonical map $O \to  \underset{n}{\underset{ \leftarrow}{\lim}} O/p^nO$ maps $p^n$ onto $P_n \bigcap  \underset{n}{\underset{ \leftarrow}{\lim}} O/p^nO$ is an immediate consequence of the definition of the inverse limit and already-established fact that the canonical map is a bijection.
(3) Construct the inverse limit of the unit groups $\left (O/p^n \right )^*$ as the subset of the direct product consisting of those tuples $(u_n)$ where $\varphi(u_j) = u_i$ for all $j \geq i$, and construct the inverse limit of the rings $O/p^n$ similarly. The definition of the product of two elements in these inverse limits now makes the isomorphism claimed in the proof clear.

Neat answer +1  , 2nd was obvious now i can see
